# Selenium Java aShot fullscreen screenshot of PDF not working

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, webdriver, ashot

I'm trying to take a fullscreen screenshot of a PDF viewed in the browser using aShot, but it's only taking a screenshot of the top of the page. I've tried on Firefox and Chrome, and neither seem to be working. Works fine on any normal webpage I've tried. I'm assuming there's something about PDFs, or PDF viewers that it doesn't like?

I've tried against an actual file path to a pdf in my downloads folder, as well as an actual HTTPS web address like this: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html and neither worked

```
driver.get("https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html");
Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
```

Comment: You may need to execute a couple javascript statements first, to scroll and/or change the overflow setting... try executing document.getElementById("viewerContainer").scrollTop=120000; (Or some number that gets you to the bottom... then take a screenshot of just the "viewContainer" element.  (or use IEDriver which will take a full shot regardless of current view... )  You may also need to add some waits/sleeps for each page to load.  (It seems to be loading stuff per page...)  You could also try executing document.getElementById("viewerContainer").style.overflow ="visible"; and scrolling main

Comment: @pcalkins added a sleep at the start of the page load and that seemed to fix a couple things. then i added the custom js to scroll to the bottom, then set the overflow to visible, and that seems to be allowing aShot to take incremental snapshots as it scrolls down from the top. however, it seems that the custom js to scroll to the bottom is only loading the last page, and all the pages in between are just showing the loading icon. also, for some reason its only taking a screenshot of half of every page, vertically. guessing ill have to do some extra configuring with aShot

Comment: @pcalkins appreciate the help btw

Comment: yeah, I was having similar results.  I think you may need to scroll one page at a time without changing the overflow for each page to load... then switch the overflow after all have loaded.  If you end up needing to take incremental shots, you might also consider using the controls at the top.